# How to change persistent storage size of a database in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to implement this constraint on a database:

***It is also possible to invest no more than 300Mbytes of persistent storage, i.e. to
double the size of TPC-HR benchmark database.***

The size of the tables that are currently in the database is around 417MB. So I'm confused about what I need to do because I can't remove the data.

I think I am misunderstanding what the constraint is. Can someone explain what needs to be done and how?

Here's the definition of the tablespace

```
CREATE TABLESPACE TPCHR
 EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL UNIFORM SIZE 256K
 SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO
 BLOCKSIZE 8K
 DATAFILE '/opt/oracle/oradata/DB/tpchr.dbf'
   SIZE 3000M AUTOEXTEND ON;
```

Comment: Your example tablespace shows "3000M" but your constraint text says "300M". What is the context of this "constraint"? Are you just trying to limit the amount of space used by a specific user, such as a tablespace? Or are you trying to constrain the size of the entire database instance (all tablespaces)? Does your constraint include log files, archived transaction logs, and other files related to db operation?

Comment: The tablespace definition that's given above is the original definition. I need to put a constraint on persistent storage and set it to 300M or extra 300M as the current size of the tables is around 417MB (so it won't fit in 300M). I'm just trying to put the constraint on TPCHR tablespace and there's no files included with the constraint.

Comment: `ALTER DATABASE
 DATAFILE 'TPCHR.DBF'
 RESIZE 300M;` Is this how to change the persistent storage size? or is this incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just downsize a datafile easily in Oracle. You first need to do a reorganization of the tables and indexes to reset the high water mark of the file, and *then* downsize the file. It is actually easier to create a new tablespace and move everything there (partial reorganization). Make sure nothing is using the schema when you do this - most of these commands can be done online while objects are in use, but they will go faster if you can move them offline.

```
-- create the new tablespace
CREATE TABLESPACE TPCHR2 
    DATAFILE 
        '/opt/oracle/oradata/DB/tpchr2.dbf' SIZE 300M;

-- grant the schema owner quota on the new tablespace
ALTER USER TPCHR_USER QUOTA UNLIMITED ON TPCHR2;

-- move tables to the new tablespace    
ALTER TABLE my_table1 MOVE TABLESPACE TPCHR2;
ALTER TABLE my_table2 MOVE TABLESPACE TPCHR2;
...

-- move lob segments to the new tablespace
ALTER TABLE my_table1 MOVE LOB (lob_column1) (TABLESPACE TPCHR2);
ALTER TABLE my_table1 MOVE LOB (lob_column2) (TABLESPACE TPCHR2);
...

-- move indexes to the new tablespace
ALTER INDEX my_index1 REBUILD TABLESPACE TPCHR2;
ALTER INDEX my_index2 REBUILD TABLESPACE TPCHR2;
...
```

Ideally you should use a tool like SQL Developer to help you construct the DDL to relocate things with the correct syntax and options for your version and environment.

If you really, really want to keep your original tablespace name, then move everything to the second tablespace, shrink the file size of the original once it is empty, then move everything back (this is full reorganization). Make sure to disable the "auto extend" option for the tablespace or it will just grow automatically again.

```
ALTER DATABASE  DATAFILE '/opt/oracle/oradata/DB/tpchr.dbf' RESIZE 300M;
ALTER DATABASE  DATAFILE '/opt/oracle/oradata/DB/tpchr.dbf' AUTOEXTEND OFF;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll try resizing the original database first and use the other method if it doesn't work.

Comment: Excuse me, but you still seem to be confusing 'tablespace' with 'database'. Perhaps it would help if you answered qeustions asked by @pmdba.  And quite frankly, that limitation of 300MBytes is microscopically small.  Why such a limitation?  Surely it's not due to cost of storage. You can buy 64 _G_byte thumb drives for less than you spend on a single lunch.